# getContentResolver() is not defined

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create small app to parse sms. I use Visual Studio with Xamarin.
I found these peace of code and want to adapt is for my need.
But getContentResolver() method is not defined. I know, that it needs application context, but i don't understand how to get it.

Could someone give me an example please?

```
// Create Sent box URI
Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java world, you'll see methods like `getContentResolver` and `setContentResolver`. In Xamarin and C# those two will be combined to one property called `ContentResolver`. The latter part of your code should be like this:

```
// Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = ContentResolver.Query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```

When porting Java code to C# (Xamarin), you can usually get basic stuff to work by capitalizing method names. With that logic, you should also modify the first line to this:

```
Uri sentURI = Uri.Parse("content://sms/sent");
```

However, this is a very simplified example. Knowing both Java and C# and how to use both the [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/) documentation will take you quite far.